# JBoss custom module development with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jboss-eap-6, jboss-modules

I've inherited code for a custom JBoss Module and I'm quite new to JBoss EAP 6.x. Currently I'm using eclipse to develop the module but to deploy a new version I've to do it manually.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Maven plugin for creating JBoss modules here: http://www.smartics.eu/smartics-jboss-modules-maven-plugin/

Use the version of your module plus a unique string eg 1.2-SNAPSHOT-c232 as the slot and use the same slot

In a post build step in Jenkins you could copy the new version to your JBoss EAP server. You might also be able to use the HTTP management interface also.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Building/bundling/deploying a JBoss module outside of Eclipse isn't the problem. I'm looking for a way to integrate module development in Eclipse so it's automatically deployed after each build i.e. after saving a file like it can be done for web applications.